# Usage of ExecSQL in UDF?

Tags: sql-server, functions

Problem:
is it possible to use sp_executesql or EXEC inside of a user defined function?

Thanks!

Comment: No, unless you really like ugly hacks. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24434679

Answer (score 1):

Not in a T-SQL function, but executing stored procedures can be done in SQLCLR functions.

An example of using a .NET / C# SQLCLR user-defined function to execute a stored procedure is shown in the following article (which I wrote):

[Stairway to SQLCLR Level 2: Sample Stored Procedure and Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/105841/)

Comment: If I understand correct, it works to execute a stored procedure inside of user defined function?

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, but only when using SQLCLR, unless you want to deal with OPENQUERY or xp_cmdshell (both of which are detailed in the link posted by @Aaron). I have updated my answer to link to an article that I wrote that shows a SQLCLR function calling a stored procedure.